# Minor Issue with Comments in Locked Questions on Several Android Browsers

Tags: bug, comments

On my Android device, when I click the "show X more comments" link in a locked question, the X more comments are revealed, but the link remains displayed with the same "show X more comments" text. Clicking the link at that point does nothing. It seems the link should disappear or change its text or something to indicate it has no more hidden comments to reveal.

An example is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature)

I searched on MSO for [show more comments link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=show+more+comments+link) and none of the existing questions are specific to this (minor) issue.

I have replicated this in Android Chrome, Android Firefox, and the default Android browser (the one that's just called "Browser").

However, the problem does not occur in Chrome on Linux Ubuntu or Firefox on Linux Ubuntu (the link does disappear).

Comment: No repro on Chrome windows either.